# Compact tripod on airplane (Europe)

Tags: tripod, travel

I'll be traveling to east Europe and for that reason I had to switch to a small compact tripod so that I could carry it easily. The new tripod, when closed, will not exceed 43 cm and it weighs below 1.5 Kg. However, it will be attached to the side of my backpack. (This tripod cannot be converted into a monopod)

However, I'm not sure if carrying it on board would be a problem or not because I have never done that and I have always put my tripod in my luggage and checked it in. But this time I will be traveling with a backpack only as the trip is short.

The other question is that if I check in the tripod, like I put it in its own case (has no protection), would the airline take good care of it?

Edit:

I called the airport police and asked them, but the said they have to see it first to confirm if it can be allowed or not.

Comment: The core of your answer is in your edit: it is up to the airport police to decide whether or not it is allowed. It might differ even which employee checks your luggage.As far as I know there are no clear guidelines regarding tripods

Comment: "would the airline take good care of it"... if you have to check in just the tripod, in a case with no protection, I don't think you can assume that good care will be taken of it. Probably nobody's going to set out to mishandle it, but it will travel along automatic conveyor belts, and may be thrown from one spot to another at some point. I would avoid this scenario.

Answer (score 1):

For my last trip to Europe I used a monopod that doubled as a cane. In the past, I have been denied entry into museums when carrying a tripod. Since the monopod does double duty, entry was allowed. However In the Louvre in Paris, the monopod was confiscated and later returned.

Answer (score 1):

There's no way anyone can give you a concrete answer here as it will ultimately come down to whomever inspects you through security.

I fly a few times a month often with my tripod and have never had any issues. It being in or out of the bag makes no difference just like it would make no difference if a knife is in your bag or out of it. I really doubt security will care.

If anything I'd be more concerned about the actual airline. Mine goes entirely flat and I put it in the laptop compartment of my camera bag. With yours just strapped to the side the airlines might not really want to stow it in the overhead bins and it seems awkward to put under the seat in front of you.

Answer (score 0):

I would say it depends on a couple of things:

- does it have spikes or sharp edges?
- could it be used as a club?
- is it small enough (including your backpack) for carry-on luggage?

I would ask at the check-in counter and have a bag ready, if it needs to be checked-in. Worst that could happen is, that you have to go to bulky luggage.

Comment: The tripod is actually this : https://www.manfrotto.nl/compact-advanced-aluminium-tripod-with-3-way-head-black , and my backpack is small I've had never any issue with that (without tripod attached), this is the backpack Case Logic SLRC-206-BLACK